# Rails reject_if not working with .build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

my code is here:

```
model A


has_many :parent_leasing_configurations, :conditions => { :parent_id=> nil }, :class_name=> 'LeasingConfiguration'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parent_leasing_configurations
```

and view file:

```
<%= f.fields_for :parent_leasing_configurations do |leasing_configuration| %>
   <tr class="<%= 'tablefbAlternate' if (tr_alter%2==0) %>">
     <td class="bdr-lt-gry bdr-rt-gry bdr-top-gry tdlfpd">
      <% if leasing_configuration.object.new_record? %>
        <%= leasing_configuration.text_field :name, :placeholder=>"Enter New Category" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= leasing_configuration.object.name %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td class="bdr-rt-gry bdr-top-gry"></td>
</tr>
```

and i am updating in contoller:

```
@current_client.update_attributes(params[:client])
```

my problem is reject_if not working for new record.so every time empty record added.

Any idea on this?

Comment: where is actual code where you are facing problem? `.build` and `reject_if`. Post related code

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Turns out I was building the nested resource in a before_action. The mistake was that I used before_action :build_nester_resource, only: [:edit, :update]. So it was building the nested resource on my update method again, and thus I wrongly thought it was the reject_if that wasn't working. I realized that was the issue because when I added 4 empty nested resources, only one was actually added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `active_record` to reject the nested attributes its blank/empty.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parent_leasing_configurations, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
```

More about **[nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)**